Xcode 16: Adding additional device support files and Setting deployment targets through Podfile
I have a few questions about setting up my podfile and xcode. I'm on Xcode version 16.0.
I want to know how to set up my podfile so that supported destinations only shows ios. I also want to set the minimum xcode version to 12. Right now supported destinations looks like this

And here is my Podfile:
platform :ios, :deployment_target => '16.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end


post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
end
   installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
    project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '16.0'
        config.build_settings['ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 'x86_64'
        config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "i386 arm64"
        config.build_settings['CODE_SIGN_STYLE'] = 'Automatic'
        config.build_settings['DEVELOPMENT_TEAM'] = '64B9S4KB35'
      end
    end
  end
end


Also my minimum deployment selections in xcode seem to be somewhat limited. For example if I select 16 it only gives me 16.6. Is there anyway I can fix this? I suppose I could go to settings -> components->add simulators to install, but is there a better way? I think I need additional device support files. I seem to recall there used to be something about being able to install additional device support files via ios Device support files github, but I think they only support up to 16.7. Here is what I see in the dropdown in xcode:

